# Why is $\chi_{[\mu}\nabla_\nu \chi_{\sigma ]} = 0$ at the Killing horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, event-horizon, vector-fields

Let $\chi$ be a Killing vector field that is null along a Killing horizon $\Sigma$

Why is $\chi_{[\mu}\nabla_\nu \chi_{\sigma ]} = 0$ at $\Sigma$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a partial answer. It assumes that the Killing field $\chi$ is *normal* to the Killing horizon. This implies that $\chi$ is null along the horizon, so it is consistent with the condition given in the OP. However, a Killing field that is null along the horizon is not necessarily orthogonal to the horizon; that's why this is only a partial answer.

Given a function $\Phi$ on spacetime and a constant $c$, the equation $\Phi=c$ defines a hypersurface. The vector field 
$$
n_a=\partial_a\Phi=\nabla_a\Phi
\tag{1}
$$
is orthogonal to that hypersurface. Now, if $\chi_a$ is any vector field orthogonal to this family of hypersurfaces, we must have 
$$
\chi_a=mn_a
\tag{2}
$$
for some function $m$. If $\chi$ is normal to the Killing horizon, then it can be written in the form (2) along the horizon.

Equation (2) implies
$$
   \nabla_b\chi_a=\nabla_b(m\nabla_a\Phi)
=
(\nabla_b m)(\nabla_a\Phi)
+
m\nabla_b\nabla_a\Phi.
\tag{3}
$$
Now consider $\chi_{[c}\nabla_b \chi_{a ]}$, where the square brackets denote complete antisymmetrization (which is what I'm assuming they mean in the OP). According to the preceding equations, 
$$
\chi_{[c}\nabla_b \chi_{a ]}
=
m(\nabla_{[c}\Phi)(\nabla_b m)(\nabla_{a]}\Phi)
+
m^2\nabla_{[c}\Phi\nabla_b\nabla_{a]}\Phi.
\tag{4}
$$
The first term in (4) is zero because of the identity
$$
(\nabla_{[c}\Phi)(\nabla_{a]}\Phi) = 0,
\tag{5a}
$$
and the second term in (4) is zero because of the identity 
$$
\nabla_{[b}\nabla_{a]}\Phi = 0
\hskip2cm
\text{(zero torsion)}.
\tag{5b}
$$
 Altogether, this shows that
$$
\chi_{[c}\nabla_b \chi_{a ]} = 0
\tag{6}
$$
whenever the vector field $\chi$ is orthogonal to the given hypersurface. This is (part of) the **Frobenius theorem**.

This derivation of equation (6) is outlined in section 2.3.3 in Poisson (2002), "An advanced course in general relativity," https://www.physics.uoguelph.ca/poisson/research/agr.pdf.

Comment: If we assume that $\chi$ is not only null along $\Sigma$, but is also in the tangent space $T\Sigma$, then it will be normal to $\Sigma$, correct?

Comment: @Rodrigo  Correct.  Since $\Sigma$ is a null hypersurface, which by definition has a null normal vector $n$ at each point, the only way another vector $\chi$ at the same point can be both null and orthogonal to $n$ (so that $\chi\in T\Sigma$) is if $\chi$ is proportional to $n$.

Comment: and that's because the metric signature is (3,1), right? It wouldn't be true if the signature were (2,2), for example.

Comment: @Rodrigo Yes, that's exactly right. I'm assuming that the signature is Lorentzian, with signature $(n,1)$.